Android Studio Debugger stops working ("Debugger is no longer active")
I am unable to use Android Studio for debugging Flutter apps.  Whenever I start an app with "flutter run" or "flutter run --debug", it starts up fine, but right after that you get a message like this:
[+8706 ms] I/art     ( 7720): Debugger is no longer active

After this, you can of course no longer debug using Android Studio.
I have tried:

With several Flutter apps, including the default demo app (File > New > "New Flutter Project"
With both emulators and a physical device
Two Android Studio versions: Giraffe (2022.3.1 Patch 4) and Jellyfish (2023.3.1, patch 1)
Two different dev workstations (one Windows 11, one Windows 10)
Two different version of Flutter (3.13.6 & 3.22.1), Dart (3.1.3 & 3.4.1) & DevTools (2.25.0 & 2.34.3)

Flutter Dev Tools work, but I would really like to also be able to use Android Studio's built-in debugger as well.
Please help.

I spent some more time on this and share my findings here, in case it helps somebody else.
The issue of the debugger disconnecting a few seconds after the app starts appears to be related to the Android API version: I created a Pixel XL VM with API 25 and it has this issue, then I created another Pixel XL VM with API 30, and the issue went away.  The only difference between the two VMs is the API version.
Unfortunately, I do not have the option to upgrade the Android version on the physical device that I am working with (it is a purpose-built device with Android 7.1.1 preinstalled; nothing else supported).
There is an easy workaround for the issue: in Android Studio, just do Run > Flutter Attach (after the debugger has disconnected).
